# Adding a UILabel to a subview is making the view it disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uilabel

I am trying to create the following view heirarchy

```
Base UIView-> UIScrollView -> UIView -> UILabel
```

In the Storyboard I created the view->UIScrollView and made the Scrollview and the base view the same size and aligned their origins.

I am then adding the subsequent UIView -> UILabels in code.

In the ViewController viewDidLoad() function I am adding the UIView and the UILabel and also setting contraints on the UIScrollView.

I am having trouble adding the UILabel. If I just add the UIView to the scrollView its working fine (I gave them different colors just to see that).

As soon as I add the UILabel to the view I see the following issues --

- the UIView seems to be disappearing and the label is getting added to the base View.
- The UILabel is always getting added to the top corner of the screen. No matter what I do its not changing.

I have a feeling these two issues are connected and I am not adding the constraints on the label properly.

It will be great if someone can point out the error in my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    let boxViewOrigin = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
    let boxViewSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width * 3, height: view.bounds.height * 3)
    let boxView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: boxViewOrigin, size: boxViewSize))
    boxView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    boxView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let scrollView = view.subviews[0] as! UIScrollView

    scrollView.addSubview(boxView)

    // Add contraints
    scrollView.contentSize = boxViewSize //CGSize(width: view.bounds.width * 3, height: view.bounds.height * 3)
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: (view.bounds.origin.x + view.bounds.width) , y: (view.bounds.origin.y + view.bounds.height) )

    /// ---- Commenting out everything from here to the end of the function makes the UIView appear properly. ------
    let nameLabel = UILabel()
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    let nameLabelOrigin = CGPoint(x: boxView.bounds.midX, y: boxView.bounds.midY )
    nameLabel.frame = CGRect(origin: nameLabelOrigin, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30) )
    nameLabel.text = "BB"
    //nameLabel.isEnabled = false

    nameLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    let verticalConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nameLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: boxView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let horizontalConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nameLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: boxView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

     boxView.addSubview(nameLabel)
     view.addConstraints([verticalConstraint, horizontalConstraint])
}
```

Comment: I think you need to set `height` and `width` constraints for `nameLabel` as well

Comment: almost sure the problem is at your vertical and horizontal contraints. Remember that you need constraints for position (that you already set) and for SIZE, that you didn't set, and when it is missing, xcode send the views to other dimension :) try to set the size of the label equal to the size of the view to check if it works, if it doesnt work, maybe try to put constraints at boxview too